# Quotient map from $\mathbb R^2$ onto $\mathbb R^2\setminus  \{(0,0)\}$

Tags: general-topology

Could you help me to find a quotient mapping from $\mathbb R^2$ onto $\mathbb R^2\setminus  \{(0,0)\}$?

Assume the standard topology on both spaces.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: polar coordinates.

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis?  Especially -- hint! -- do you know about the complex exponential function?